# Can't connect to EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

**startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using MyQuotesApp.models;

using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace MyQuotesApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath);
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("config.json");
            configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<QuotesAppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

**project.json dependencies**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

**If I use EntityFramework.Core v7.0.0.0-rc1-final I get the following error:**

I have a red line under options.UseSqlServer on this line:

```
.AddDbContext<QuotesAppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]));
```

The error says:

> The type 'EntityOptionsBuilder' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'EntityFramework.Core, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

**If I use EntityFramework.Core v7.0.0-beta5 I get the following error:**

A red line under AddEntityFramework on this line:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
```

The error reads:

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddEntityFramework' and no extension method 'AddEntityFramework'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I look online though it seems all of the tutorials I find for setting up the connection involve a line similar to mine which is producing that error.  Perhaps this is a simple issue and my lack of experience in c# keeps me from knowing the obvious answer? How can I get this stupid thing connected to my SQL DB?

Comment: Well isn't it telling you to add EntityFramework.Core???

Comment: Don't you see in my project.json that EntityFramework.Core is already added? I can see it in my references list. It is infact added.

Comment: can you move the entity framework core stuff closer to the top of the list in the config file? The order might matter and you have your commands and sql server before you declare EF itself..

Comment: I am pretty sure order does not matter in the dependencies but just in case I changed the order so Core was before the other EntityFramework stuff and it did not change the error.

Comment: try removing everything related to EF and just put this `"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",`... EF should solve other dependencies by itself... also in your package config you have different versions running for some of your EF dependencies, that might also be a problem... hope this helps :)

Comment: Dude... yes.  I then had to fix another error with a missing IApplicationEnvironment object but it works. Can you make that an answer Spluf and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing everything related to EF and just put this:

```
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
```

EF should solve other dependencies by itself... also in your package config you have different versions running for some of your EF dependencies, that might also be a problem... glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your connection  strings are correct. Ensure that the relevent nuget packages are installed correctly. Once your nuget packages are installed correctly and your connection string is correct with a proper name that youre referencing e.g. `<add name="DbName" connectionString="xyn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
Ensure you refer to your db context as DbName or whatever is the name in the connection string. Ensure you use the correct using `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Ensure you ahve the coirrect config entity for EF e.g.

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

This is a child element of `<configuration>`